# Is Hanuman the first writer of Ramayana?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, hanuman

Many great sages wrote Ramayana in different time and yuga. But great Sage Valmiki is the first writer of Ramayana who wrote whole Ramayana even before the story of Ramayana is completed in real life. Means Ramayana (Story of Rama's life) was being written by Valmiki from birth to death even when Rama was alive. He wrote down all incidents of Rama's  life before it actually happened because Valmiki was able to see future. But recently I came to know about a new fact in which it is stated that Hanuman was the first writer of Ramayana. Here is how...

After defeating Ravana, Hanuman went to a mountain (don't remember name right now) and start writing Ramayana with his nails. When he did complete his Ramayana then Great Sage Valmiki saw Hanuman's Ramayana and found that his Ramayana is far more superior and better than Valmiki's (mine) Ramayana. So he got tense by seeing Humaana's version of Ramayana. He got afraid that if world will see Hanuman's far superior Ramayana then no one will even notice his Ramayana and no one will praise his work. So Valmiki politely asked to Hanuman that...

> Ramayana Should only be written by human devotee, not by Lord or incarnation of Lord. Since you are incarnation of Lord Shiva, so you should not write Ramayana

Lord Hanuman got convinced by Valmiki's words and destroyed his version of Ramayana so that no one ever could see his Ramayana and world can only witness Valmiki's Ramayana.

So is it really true that Hanuman wrote Ramayana before Sage Valmiki and his version of Ramayana was more superior than Valmiki's Ramayana?

Comment: Actually, I heard the story the other way around. Hanuman wrote the Ramayana but after reading the version by Valmiki, he thought that Valmiki Ramayana was better than his and discarded the Ramayana. I don't know the source of this story either.

Comment: @SreeCharan My source of this information is YouTube. If you will search on youtube by typing this "Top facts about Hanuman" then you will watch many videos that includes this story.

Comment: @SreeCharan Even i heard the same. It is said that at end of Kali Yuga,  Ramayana by Hanuman.will be found.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Can you please give some more information about this. This is completely new info for me that "End of kali yuga Hanuman's Ramayana will be found". Please tell more...

Comment: Many Great Sages has wrote Ramayana in different time and yuga? Actually, in Puranas also, valmiki Ramayana will be told. Some difference will be there due to change in voice and sometimes Kalpa bheda(Padma Purana) . Others compose it but don't write it again. If you want to name Tulsidas,he is not a sage. If you want to know more about the Hanuman story, don't discuss in comments. Use chat room.

Comment: There are no scriptures that mention the Hanumad Ramayana.  But according to folklore, Hanuman threw the tablets containing the Hanumad Ramayana into the ocean.  And then in the time of Kalidasa, a tablet was discovered in the ocean written in an extinct script, and Kalidasa looked at it and claimed that it was one of the tablets of the Hanumad Ramayana.

Comment: I don't know whether Kalidasa was right about that or not, but either way it at least suggests that the concept of a Hanumad Ramayana was there in the time of Kalidasa.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan **There are no scriptures that mention the Hanumad Ramayana**. May be because Hanuman didn't want that his Ramayana come out, So to kept this hidden/secrete (that he also wrote Ramayana) He destroyed his Ramayana and never talked about it. May be that's why scriptures didn't mentioned this much because it's a secrete which Hanuman didn't want to disclose.

Comment: @Rishabh Or it could be that the notion of the Hanumad Ramayana is just something invented in folklore, just like the notion of Hanuman opening his chest and showing Rama and Sita.

Comment: Hanuman narrated the ramayana to Sita in sundara kanda. Valmiki reported that hanuman sang the ramayana in his kaavya. Therefore it is interpreted as hanuman singing the ramayana before valmiki. Tulasidasa also pays obeisance to both valmiki and hanuman in the same invocation sloka perhaps for this reason.

Comment: They say that kakbhusundi traveled to alternate timelines to witness Ramayan 11 times. Must be that they were authored by the respective sages of those timelines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes** Lord Hanuman wrote [Ramayan](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/kishkindha/sarga66/kishkindha_66_prose.htm).

> Another parable is told that Hanuma is the first one to script Ramayana on claytablets, recording each and every detail of what Rama did. Having finished his writing he brought those claytablets to Rama, to bless that work.

**Conversation with Lord Ram :**

> Rama humbly said to Hanuma, "I have not done anything great to be
>   recorded this laboriously... I have done my righteous duty...that's
>   all..." **Then Hanuma was upset. Dejected by the slighting away of
>   'his great deeds as simple acts of duty' by Rama, Hanuma brought those
>   clay tablets to seashore, recited each verse, and broke each tablet on
>   his knee and threw them into sea.** This writing is called **hanumad
>   ramayana.** This work is unavailable from that time.

**Last Piece of Hanumad Ramayan was found by Mahakavi Kalidas** :

> But one tablet came to shore afloat on the sea, which is retrieved
>   during the period of Mahakavi Kalidasa, and hung at a public place to
>   be deciphered by scholars. On that tablet only one foot of a stanza is
>   available That foot says **"Oh! Ravana, those your ten heads, on which you lifted of Mt. Kailah, the abode of Shiva, are now bumped on battlefield by the claws of crows and eagles, know what has happened to your high-headed Decahedral pride, at the hands of virtue..."**.

**Kalidasa deciphers this stanza and informs that it is from hanumad ramayana, recorded by Hanuma, but an extinct script.** And Kalidasa salutes that clayplate for he is fortunate enough to see at least one stanza of hanumad ramaayana. It is said that none can conclusively narrate about Hanuma, for he is many faceted. He is symbolic for unwavering dedication to righteousness, unstinting performance of entrusted duties, unfailing talents in service. So the tradition holds Hanuma dear...

**CONCLUSION :**

**Lord Hanuman also wrote Ramayan by himself and was destroyed by himself but there is No Mentioning that he was the First writer**

Comment: You missed a phrase in the beginning, it says "**Another parable is told that** Hanuma is the first one to script Ramayana on claytablets,...."  Hence it is just a parable and has no basis in scriptures. To keep it clear, adding those bold part is important in the answer. Otherwise, some might mistake it is real. Those footnotes are added by translator of the Valmikiramayan.net. Not in the original Ramayana.

Comment: @SreeCharan friend is the site not official

Comment: Friend, The Ramayana given in the site is official and authentic. But this story about Hanumad Ramayana is listed in the site under Parable section of the site. As the life of Hanuman was discussed in the relevant chapter, they also mentioned the related parables of Hanumad Ramayana.